# set NaN values in pandas dataframe to 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a large pandas dataframe and am struggling to set NaN values of specific columns to 1.

The column types for the columns I want to work on are below:

```
guests = object, beds = float64, bathrooms = float64, bedrooms = object.
```

I have tried these methods but none have worked:

```
df['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms'] = df['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms'].replace(np.nan, 1)
```

```
df['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms'].fillna(1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: What error you receiving ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `inplace` as you are modifying a copy of the DataFrame, but [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) back or [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df[['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms']].fillna(1))
```

Or:

```
cols = ['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms']
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(1)
```

Or limit the values in [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) using a dictionary:

```
cols = ['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms']
df.fillna({k: 1 for k in cols}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with convert columns names by dictionary to `1`:

```
print (dict.fromkeys(['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms'], 1))
{'guests': 1, 'bedrooms': 1, 'beds': 1, 'bathrooms': 1}

df = df.fillna(dict.fromkeys(['guests', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'bathrooms'], 1))
```